# ngif condition not working for multiple conditions

Tags: angular

I'm using a navigation bar in angular with 10 pages. This should not be shown to 
three routes:

1. welcome
2. client-login
3. reset

It is working for single condition not for all three:

```
<div
    *ngIf="
      router.url !== '/advocate-home/welcome' ||
      router.url !== '/advocate-home/client-login' ||
      router.url !== '/advocate-home/reset-password'
    "
  >
<nav bar>
</div>
```

This code hides the navbar for that route, but I need to hide for 3 routes:

```
<div
    *ngIf="
      router.url !== '/advocate-home/welcome'

    "
  >
<nav bar RENDERED>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you can use 'ngSwitch' in this case.

Comment: Basic boolean operators. Consider that the url is `/advocate-home/reset-password`, then two of your conditions will be true. What happens when you OR (`||`) those? You want _all_ your conditions to be fulfilled, so AND.

Comment: change || to &&

Answer (score 1):

You should use `&&`, not `||`:

```
<div
    *ngIf="
      router.url !== '/advocate-home/welcome'
      && router.url !== '/advocate-home/client-login'
      && router.url !== '/advocate-home/reset-password'
    "
 >
```

This logical operator `||` means `OR`, however `&&` means `AND`.

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

> Logical AND (`&&`) `expr1 && expr2`.  If `expr1` can be converted to `true`,
>   returns `expr2`; else, returns `expr1`.
>
> Logical OR (`||`) `expr1 || expr2`.   If
>   `expr1` can be converted to `true`, returns `expr1`; else, returns `expr2`.

```js
let x = 3;
let y = -1;

console.log(x > 0 && y > 0);
// expected output: false

console.log(x > 0 || y > 0);
// expected output: true

console.log(!(x > 0 || y > 0));
// expected output: false
```

Answer (score 0):

If the boolean operators confuse you, you could consider using an array:

```
*ngIf="!['/advocate-home/welcome', '/advocate-home/client-login', '/advocate-home/reset-password'].includes(router.url)"
```